# Using an ISAPI Filter in Visual Studio Development Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, isapi-redirect, isapi-extension

I'm trying to get a current web application running on my local machine, for dev purposes... the previous developer left abruptly and didn't document ANYTHING.

Basically, it uses an ISAPI filter, installed into IIS for some url redirection...
this is fine, but, i want to set it up on my local dev machine...
How can i go about doing that? so that my project runs when i hit f5....

i will probably end up using an httphandler or something in the very near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the ISAPI filter to IIS using the IIS Management Console. You add ISAPI filters globally at the server level, or at the Web Site level (and the options to look at them) only exist if you have selected the right node.

(Details of using the tool depend on IIS6 vs IIS7.)

If the ISAPI filter is installed, then it should be working, but without documentation you are stuck looking at source or debugging.